# ASP.Net chat application javascript pop-up window

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am designing an ASP.Net chat application.  I have an online user list which are LinkButtons in a ListView.  I want to click one of them and open a pop-up window.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Set your LinkButtons so they have an onclick attribute that opens a popup window.

Codebehind:

```
Dim username as String = "foo"
lnkbtn.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:openWindow(" & username & ");return false;")
'The "return false" part is important - it stops the LinkButton from doing a postback.
```

Client-side:

```
function openWindow(username) {
    window.open(my_url + username); //Where my_url is the URL that you want to open.
}
```

`username` is just there as an example of how you can pass values through to Javascript.